# Firefox preserve-3d child element click events not working

Tags: firefox, 3d, css-transforms

I'm trying to get this [codepen](https://codepen.io/panfilov/pen/GogJVy) to work on the latest firefox (v75.0) at the time of writing.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #eee;
  user-select: none;
}

[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

#slider {
  height: 35vw;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 1000px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

#slider label {
  margin: auto;
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease;
}

#s1:checked ~ #slide4, #s2:checked ~ #slide5,
#s3:checked ~ #slide1, #s4:checked ~ #slide2,
#s5:checked ~ #slide3 {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.37);
  transform: translate3d(-30%,0,-200px);
}

#s1:checked ~ #slide5, #s2:checked ~ #slide1,
#s3:checked ~ #slide2, #s4:checked ~ #slide3,
#s5:checked ~ #slide4 {
  box-shadow: 0 6px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3), 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  transform: translate3d(-15%,0,-100px);
}

#s1:checked ~ #slide1, #s2:checked ~ #slide2,
#s3:checked ~ #slide3, #s4:checked ~ #slide4,
#s5:checked ~ #slide5 {
  box-shadow: 0 13px 25px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3), 0 11px 7px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.19);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

#s1:checked ~ #slide2, #s2:checked ~ #slide3,
#s3:checked ~ #slide4, #s4:checked ~ #slide5,
#s5:checked ~ #slide1 {
  box-shadow: 0 6px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3), 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  transform: translate3d(15%,0,-100px);
}

#s1:checked ~ #slide3, #s2:checked ~ #slide4,
#s3:checked ~ #slide5, #s4:checked ~ #slide1,
#s5:checked ~ #slide2 {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.37);
  transform: translate3d(30%,0,-200px);
}

#slide1 { background: #00BCD4 }
#slide2 { background: #4CAF50 }
#slide3 { background: #CDDC39 }
#slide4 { background: #FFC107 }
#slide5 { background: #FF5722 }
```

```html
<section id="slider">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="s1">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="s2">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="s3" checked>
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="s4">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="s5">
  <label for="s1" id="slide1"></label>
  <label for="s2" id="slide2"></label>
  <label for="s3" id="slide3"></label>
  <label for="s4" id="slide4"></label>
  <label for="s5" id="slide5"></label>
</section>
```

The issues appears to be that I cannot click on the any of the label elements to trigger the carousel change.  It seems that preserve-3d is not allowing that.

Does anyone have any thoughts?  This is working in Chrome and Safari.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The label elements are *under* the slider, so the slider prevents clicking on them.

Set pointer events none on the container, and reset it to auto on labels, to get it working

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #eee;
  user-select: none;
}

[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

#slider {
  height: 35vw;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 1000px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  pointer-events: none; /* added */
}

#slider label {
  margin: auto;
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease;
  pointer-events: auto;  /* added */
}

#s1:checked ~ #slide4, #s2:checked ~ #slide5,
#s3:checked ~ #slide1, #s4:checked ~ #slide2,
#s5:checked ~ #slide3 {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.37);
  transform: translate3d(-30%,0,-200px);
}

#s1:checked ~ #slide5, #s2:checked ~ #slide1,
#s3:checked ~ #slide2, #s4:checked ~ #slide3,
#s5:checked ~ #slide4 {
  box-shadow: 0 6px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3), 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  transform: translate3d(-15%,0,-100px);
}

#s1:checked ~ #slide1, #s2:checked ~ #slide2,
#s3:checked ~ #slide3, #s4:checked ~ #slide4,
#s5:checked ~ #slide5 {
  box-shadow: 0 13px 25px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3), 0 11px 7px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.19);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

#s1:checked ~ #slide2, #s2:checked ~ #slide3,
#s3:checked ~ #slide4, #s4:checked ~ #slide5,
#s5:checked ~ #slide1 {
  box-shadow: 0 6px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3), 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  transform: translate3d(15%,0,-100px);
}

#s1:checked ~ #slide3, #s2:checked ~ #slide4,
#s3:checked ~ #slide5, #s4:checked ~ #slide1,
#s5:checked ~ #slide2 {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.37);
  transform: translate3d(30%,0,-200px);
}

#slide1 { background: #00BCD4 }
#slide2 { background: #4CAF50 }
#slide3 { background: #CDDC39 }
#slide4 { background: #FFC107 }
#slide5 { background: #FF5722 }
```

```html
<section id="slider">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="s1">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="s2">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="s3" checked>
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="s4">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="s5">
  <label for="s1" id="slide1"></label>
  <label for="s2" id="slide2"></label>
  <label for="s3" id="slide3"></label>
  <label for="s4" id="slide4"></label>
  <label for="s5" id="slide5"></label>
</section>
```